# DataTables showing error despite showing the result

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I'm inserting data into my dataTable through a json object. The data is being displayed correctly, although it shows an error. I've checked everything and I can't find any mistakes in my code. Can you help me find what is causing the error. Thank you.

> DataTables warning: table id=Missingtables - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

```js
var table_err = [{
  table_name: "apm_exceptions"
}, {
  table_name: "apm_app_parameters"
}];
var nametable = $("#Missingtables").DataTable({
  "data": table_err,
  "columns": [{
      "searchable": false,
      "orderable": false,
      "targets": 0
    },
    {
      "data": "table_name"
    }
  ],
  "order": [
    [1, 'asc']
  ],
});

nametable.on('order.dt search.dt', function() {
  nametable.column(0, {
    search: 'applied',
    order: 'applied'
  }).nodes().each(function(cell, i) {
    cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
  });
}).draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="Missingtables">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S.No</th>
      <th>TableName</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't find anything wrong after checking the website u suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify data property name for each column if your data is an array of objects using [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) option. If there is no associated data property name, use `"data": null` along with `"defaultContent": ""`.

For example:

```
var nametable = $("#Missingtables").DataTable({
  "data": table_err,
  "columns": [{
      "searchable": false,
      "orderable": false,
      "data": null,
      "defaultContent": ""
    },
    {
      "data": "table_name"
    }
  ],
  "order": [
    [1, 'asc']
  ],
});
```